# Did anyone find solution for Trying to get property 'pivot' of non-object?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I tried to make relation btw organizer and user using pivot table, but when i tried to display the output its showing me error.
OrganizeController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $organize = Organize::find($id);

    return dd($organize->pivot->name);
}
```

Organize.php

```
namespace App;

use App\OrganizeUser;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Organize extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: if your relation is many to many you don't need to have `->withPivot('user_id')` in your model and to access it, you need to have something like `    return dd($organize->users);`

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function show($id){
    $organize = Organize::find($id);
    $organize->user()->get();
}
```